# How to remove square brackets from keys in array of objects (TypeScript)?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to remove all existing square brackets from the `entries` keys in the following array of objects:

```
data: [
   {title: "Title1", entries: { 'Entry1': 333333, '[ABC]Entry2': 1234, 'Entry3': 5555 }}, 
   {title: "Title2", entries: { '[ABC]Entry1': 5555, 'Entry2': 4444,'Entry3': 2222 }}
]
```

My goal is to have `ABCEntry2` and `ABCEntry1` instead of `[ABC]Entry2` and `[ABC]Entry1`.

For that, I've mapped through the `data`, then mapped through the `Object.keys` of `x.entries` within in, checked if there's any bracket existing in the key, and, if so, replaced it with `''`.

Here is the code:

```
data.map(x => {
   Object.keys(x.entries).map( y => {
      if(y.includes('[') && y.includes(']')) {
         y = y.replace(/\[/g, '').replace(/]/g, '');
         console.log("I have no brackets: ", y);
      }
   })
   console.log("I still have brackets: ", x.entries);         
})

console.log("I have brackets here too: ", data);
```

If I print the `y` value, I can see the desired result with no square brackets. However, I lose it if I try to print/use it outside of the `Object.keys(x.entries)` mapping. Instead, I am getting the original data with the square brackets again.

I wonder if there is a way to have my updates on `x.entries` and entire `data` without creating a new variable and storing the changes there? So that when I print `data`, it shows the updated entries with no square brackets in its keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `y` inside the callback doesn't mutate the original object. You can map the key to a new key and then construct a new object from the mapped entries instead.

```js
const data=[{title:"Title1",entries:{'Entry1':333333,'[ABC]Entry2':1234,'Entry3':5555}},{title:"Title2",entries:{'[ABC]Entry1':5555,'Entry2':4444,'Entry3':2222}}];

const newData = data.map((object) => ({
    ...object,
    entries: Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object.entries)
        .map(([key, value]) => [
            key.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, ""),
            value,
        ])),
}));

console.log(newData);
```

---

For a solution that mutates the original `data` array, you need to loop over the keys, get a new key, then delete the old key while assigning the new one.

```js
const data=[{title:"Title1",entries:{'Entry1':333333,'[ABC]Entry2':1234,'Entry3':5555}},{title:"Title2",entries:{'[ABC]Entry1':5555,'Entry2':4444,'Entry3':2222}}];

data.forEach((object) => {
    for (const key in object.entries) {
        const newKey = key.replace(/\[/g, "").replace(/\]/g, "");
        const value = object.entries[key];
        
        delete object.entries[key];
        
        object.entries[newKey] = value;
    }
});

console.log(data);
```